# How to center an element on website?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make the element which has id "all" centered on the overall website. Is there something wrong in my code? It does not work properly

```
#all{
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #808080;
}
```

Comment: The flexbox settings you applied will only center all child elements inside the element with the id all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` to center an absolutely positioned element horizontally.

```css
#all{
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  top: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #808080;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="all">all</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to code like below

```
#all{
    position: absolute;
    width: 55%;
    top: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-27.5%;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #808080;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use it with 2d translate to vertical align it in all screen sizes, as this:

```
.myClass {
   position:fixed;
   width: 55%; // or what ever fixed or precentage value
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   // height: 150px; // if height is known 
   // margin-top: -75px; // if height is known - minus half the height
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%); // if height is unknown
}
```